# is there any video format i can use in html5 video that will cover all browsers?

Tags: html, video

As I understand it all browsers bar Firefox and Opera support h.264/mp4 videos files, to cover firefox I would need to provide a flash fallback file or .ogg file. Is this correct or is there 1 file type I could use that would cover all?

Answer (score 0):

i think thats correct. look at this table for html5 video browser support

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: w3schools is a terrible site that often has incorrect info (see http://w3fools.com/). For support info, it's generally better to check caniuse.com (e.g. http://caniuse.com/#search=video%20format).